# Reduced Row vs. Reduced Row-Echelon?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a little confused as to what the difference between reduced row and reduced row-echelon is. I have this following problem:

> Row reduce the following matrix in as few steps as possible.
>   \begin{bmatrix}3&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0\\-1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\-1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\-1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&1&1\\0&0&0&0&1&2&1\\0&0&0&0&1&1&2\end{bmatrix}

I figure using simple row operations would reduce it, but I'm confused as to which method I should use. Any help?

Comment: Did you do any research? This is a pretty basic definition you could easily find online.

Answer (score 1):

[There **is** a difference between **row-echelon form**, and **reduced row-echelon form.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

> Specifically, a matrix is in **row echelon form** if:
>
> - all nonzero rows (rows with at least one nonzero element) are above any rows of all zeroes (all zero rows, if any, belong at the bottom of the matrix), and
> - the leading coefficient (the first nonzero number from the left, also called the pivot) of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it (some texts add the condition that the leading coefficient must be 1).
>
> These two conditions imply that all entries in a column below a leading coefficient are zeros. [2]

$$ $$

> A matrix is in **reduced row echelon form** (also called row canonical form) if it satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - It is in row echelon form.
> - Every leading coefficient is 1 and is the only nonzero entry in its column.

I suspect that is what you are asking.  The main difference is that one can reach *row-echelon form* more quickly.  The canonical form of row-echelon form is **reduced row-echelon may require additional elementary row** operations.